# Datatype mismatch in criteria expression using c# in access

Tags: c#

I am having a problem with DateToday throwing me an exception:

> "Datatype mismatch in criteria expression"

when I try to update date today to String `NewYork`. The Datatype of my DateToday is `DateTime`. The problem exist in clause "Where", but when I try to run CommandText without the clause where everything goes just fine

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
String dateToday = date.ToString("M/dd/yyyy");
String NewYork = dateToday + " 12:00:00 AM";
if (NewYork == label2.Text)
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "update SalesPerDay set [salesOfToday]=[salesOfToday]+" + (TextBox1.Text) + ",[DateToday] = '" + NewYork + "' where [DateToday]='" + NewYork + "'";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you ever heard the term _sql injection_? Use sql parameters. That will also fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just before I start, you can get a Date from a DateTime using `DateTime.Now.Date`.

An easy trick I find to avoid Datatype mismatch when dealing with Date time strings is to format it in the format `yyyy/MM/dd` i.e. year first. When year is first the order of month and day should always be the same.

However to you can probably accomplish what you are trying to do by using
`var NewYork = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("o");` and using the result for your datetime in your query.